# Is is possible to alternate a property each time it is called?

Tags: c#, properties

I have the class below in my project and for a test purpose, each time I access the my_byte property I want its elements to alternate.

```
namespace my_namespace
{
    public class my_class
    {
        public  byte[] my_byte { get; set; } = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
    }
}
```

What I mean is when my_byte is accessed it now returns `0x00, 0x00, 0x00`. What I want is next time it is called it will return `0xFF, 0x00, 0x00` and the other time again `0x00, 0x00, 0x00` so forth and so on... So it will alternate.

Is this even possible?

**EDIT:**

In a main class the method is called as:

```
    namespace my_namespace
    {
        public class Main_Class
        {
    Class_X obj = new Class_X()
    
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        byte[] my_received_data= obj.my_method(a, b, c); 
}}
```

This my_method is in a class:

```
namespace my_namespace
{
    class Class_X
    {
      public byte[] my_method(byte[] a, int b, bool c)

        {
        
        //here method works properly
}
}
```

then I have an interface

```
   namespace my_namespace
    {
  
        
        public interface IMy_Interface
        {
            byte[] another_method(byte[] a, bool b, Class_Z c);
        }
    }
```

Then here is a class of the interface above:

```
namespace my_namespace
{
    public class Class_Q:IMy_Interface
    {
        my_class obj_x = new my_class();
        
                public byte[] another_method(byte[] a, bool b, Class_Z c)
        {
       
       //this calles properties from my_class
}

}
}
```

Here is the class with props in question:

```
namespace my_namespace
{
    public class my_class
    {
        public  byte[] my_byte { get; set; } = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
    }
}
```

As you see before each time the props are retuned, new obj_x created which doesnt let the boolean status to alternate :(

**EDIT2:**

```
namespace my_namespace
{
    class my_class 
    {
        const int index = 2;
        private bool alternate = true;
   
        public byte[] SendT(byte[] t_sent, bool test_port)
        {
            byte[] returnValue = null;

            if (t_sent[2] == 0xD3)
            {
             

                if (alternate)
                {
                    returnValue = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00  };
                }

                else 
                {
                    returnValue = {0xFF, 0x00, 0x00   };

                }

                alternate = !alternate;
            }

            else
            {
                return null;
            }

            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is, but you shouldn't to that with a property. A property getter is - what the name suggests - getting the value. Don't change the value when accessed. Instead use a method like `GetAndIncrement` - although, what's the purpose of this?

Comment: You could store two arrays in `byte[]` fields and swap them in a custom getter. Or do you mean change the array contents of the same array? But yeah, kinda weird thing to do.

Comment: Do you need a new instance of my_class each time?  Could this be changed to a singleton?

Comment: I dont need my_class at all. All can be moved to Class_Q:IMy_Interface as long as we dont create new object. But I couldn't embed it into it.:(

Comment: The compiler errors are from the byte array initialization. returnValue = { ... }  needs to be returnValue = new byte[] { .... }

Comment: still doesn't alternate

Comment: I added a static version that can be called from within your if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want your 2 byte arrays and a boolean which will flip back and forth each time the property is accessed.

```
namespace my_namespace
{
    public class AlternatePropertyClass
    {
        public byte[] AlternatingBytes
        { 
            get
            {
                // Get the alternating array value
                //
                return AlternatingByteArray();
            }
        }

        // The byte arrays to alternate between
        //
        private byte[] bytes1 = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
        private byte[] bytes2 = new byte[] { 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00 };

        // The state variable indicating which array to return
        //
        private bool isFirstByteArray = false;

        // The alternating function which changes the state variable back and forth
        //
        private byte[] AlternatingByteArray()
        {
            // Flip the value of the boolean
            //
            isFirstByteArray = !isFirstByteArray;

            // Return the appropriate array based on the state of isFirstByteArray as a ternary operation
            //
            return isFirstByteArray ? bytes1 : bytes2;
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
var c = new AlternatePropertyClass();
Console.WriteLine(c.AlternatingBytes[0].ToString());
Console.WriteLine(c.AlternatingBytes[0].ToString());
Console.WriteLine(c.AlternatingBytes[0].ToString());
Console.WriteLine(c.AlternatingBytes[0].ToString());
```

Results:

```
0
255
0
255
```

Here is a static version that can be called from wherever.

```
public static class AlternatingBytes
{
    private static byte[] bytes1 = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
    private static byte[] bytes2 = new byte[] { 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00 };

    private static bool isFirstByteArray = false;

    public static byte[] GetAlternatingBytes()
    {
        isFirstByteArray = !isFirstByteArray;

        return isFirstByteArray ? bytes1 : bytes2;
    }
}
```

From your code you would call it like:

```
var bytes = AlternatingBytes.GetAlternatingBytes();
```

Comment: This is returning only the the first option. Did you try it?

Comment: Seems in my case the object is created each at each access since I reach this class through interface

Comment: Can you show us how the code is being used please?

Comment: very difficult to share many classes i will try

Comment: If there is a new instance of this class being created each time, none of these solutions would work.  The state variable would need to be persisted and applied to the new instance.

Comment: I think thats the pronlem I dont know how to solve it but Im trying to add more details to the question.

Comment: Please see my EDIT2. I moved it but now I get CS1002 error says curly bracket and ; needed but there is not missing in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Very possible. You can write your own `get` method and use a field (or another property) to control the alternation. Here's an example:

```
namespace my_namespace
{
    public class my_class
   {
      private bool alternate = false;
      public byte[] My_byte
      {
         get
         {
            byte[] returnValue;
            if (alternate)
            {
               returnValue = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
            }
            else
            {
               returnValue = new byte[] { 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00 };
            }
            alternate = !alternate;

            return returnValue;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I also recommend you spend some time with the MS Docs. The page on [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) maybe be useful.

Edit - Here's a main that repeatedly gets and prints the values:

```
      public static void Main()
      {
         var x = new my_class();
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         {
            foreach (var y in x.My_byte) {
               Console.WriteLine(y);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("=====");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
         }
      }
```

Sample output:

`255                                                                                                                0                                                                                                                       0                                                                                                                       =====                                                                                                                   0                                                                                                                       0                                                                                                                       0                                                                                                                       =====                                                                                                                   255                                                                                                                     0                                                                                                                       0                                                                                                                       =====                                                                                                                   0                                                                                                                       0                                                                                                                       0                                                                                                                       =====`

Comment: Can you check it, looks good but in my case it only shows the bottom return. Can there be something missing?

Comment: It works for me, returning first `{255, 0, 0}`, then `{0, 0, 0}`, then `{255, 0, 0}`, alternating indefinitely.

Comment: strange it only returns the second one, and in the other answer returns only the first one. I call it from a main class,

Comment: I've updated my answer with simple logic to get and print the values.

Comment: The problem is private bool alternate = false; never updates to true it is always false

Comment: Seems in my case the object is created each at each access since I reach this class through interface

Comment: Please see my EDIT2. I moved it but now I get CS1002 error says curly bracket and ; needed but there is not missing in my code.

Comment: If you're recreating the object each time you access it, then you are losing the stored state. You'll need to use a persistent object, or a static one.

As for missing curly brackets and semicolons, I feel confident that you can figure those out :)